# How to do a "if not" in Bash without a test?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to use the return value of a bash function in a 'if not' statement.
The following is an example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function myfunction () {
 if [ $1 = "one" ]; then
  return 1
 elif [ $1 = "two" ]; then
  return 2
 else
  return 0
 fi
}

if myfunction "two"; then
 # just using echo as an example here
 echo yep $?
else
 # just using echo as an example here
 echo nope $?
fi
```

Is there a way to modify the part 'if myfunction "two"' in a way that this script echoes 'yep 2'? I can only figure out this ugly way. How can can I solve this a better way?

Answer (score 2):

`if myfunction "two"` in pseudocode is `if the myfunction return code is zero when run with a single argument "two"`. If you want to reverse the comparison (`is not zero`) you can simply add a `!` between `if` and `myfunction`.

Comment: That works great - except that $? is changed as well. But thats how the system works I guess...

Comment: @Den Yes, `$?` always holds the result of the last command. You are supposed to save it to some other variable if you want to keep the result of a specific command for later.

Comment: @Den Note that `if ...; then ...` can be rewritten as `...; if $? = 0; then ...` for elided parts in the same order. That may be more in line with what you want to do, because then you have a good place in which to save the value of `$?` to somewhere else.

Comment: Ah, right, silly me.

Comment: Note that this "reversal" of the exit code involves some information loss: Instead of a value from 0 through 255 you'll get either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but:

```
myfunction two; (( $? == 2 )) && echo yes || echo no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myfunction "two"
myvar=$?
if [ $myvar -gt 0 ]; then
 echo yep $myvar
else
 echo nope $myvar
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the echoing from within the function? This should be straightforward:

```
myfunction() {
    case "$1" in 
        one) echo "nope 0" ;;
        two) echo "yep 2" ;;
    esac
}
myfunction one
myfunction two
```

Comment: The echoing is only to illustrate the example. The real script is only about the if...